# How to deal with zero in differentiable manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry

In the topic of submanifolds, the following is important:

For all point $p$ in a subspace $N$ of a differentiable manifold $M$, if there is smooth chart $(U,\phi)$ of $M$ such that $\phi{(p)}=0$.

My question is that whether the manifold $M$ has to have a chart $(U,\phi)$ that $\phi(p)=0$. If $M$ do not have charts send $p$ to $0$, how to deal with this situation? We treat $M$ with no submanifolds? Or defaultly think $M$ always has a chart sent $p$ to zero?

Comment: Hint: If $\phi$ is a chart, think of new charts of the form $\phi(x) - v$, for a fixed vector $v\in R^n$.

Comment: $0$ is just convenient since it's the only point (vector) we all can agree on in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: You mean: let $\phi(x)=v$. Define the new map as $\phi(x)-v$. Then the property: "for each points, there is a chart that send the point to zero" will automatically be satisfied?